# CSS Rotate Transform not Staying in new Position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

I am trying to do what should be a simple rotate transform on some text using the CSS transform and transition properties when an element is clicked however, the rotation doesn't seem to stay in its new position.

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="accordion-btn">
    <span class="arrowGreen">&gt;</span> <a href="#">Show help</a>
</div>
```

I have the CSS transition for the arrow set as below:

```
.arrowGreen {
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

I am then applying the transform using a jQuery click function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion-btn').click(function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    if ($(this).find('.arrowGreen').css('transform') != "rotate(90deg)")
    {
        $(this).find('.arrowGreen').css({ '-ms-transform': 'rotate(90deg)', '-moz-transform': 'rotate(90deg)', '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(90deg)', 'transform': 'rotate(90deg)' });
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).find('.arrowGreen').css({ '-ms-transform': 'rotate(-90deg)', '-moz-transform': 'rotate(-90deg)', '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(-90deg)', 'transform': 'rotate(-90deg)'});
    }
}
```

This works to an extent. When the element is clicked the span does rotate, however, when it gets to 90 degrees, it then automatically snaps back to its default state. It will then no longer rotate on click, however the transform styles are still attached to the element when inspecting it in developer tools. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance,
Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordion-btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.arrowGreen').toggleClass('rotate90');
  });
});
```

```css
.arrowGreen {
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
}
.rotate90 {
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-btn">
  <span class="arrowGreen">&gt;</span>  <a href="#">Show help</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and it works. The float doesn't work with my design however but without it the rotation still returns to default. I then tried making the span display inline-block (as float makes it block I believe) and this seems to have fixed it. Doesn't seem to like inline elements from what I can gather?

Comment: @AaronUmhoefer: oh my apologies. span with 'inline-block' works fine..
Sorry for that. Anyway let me change the code also... :)

Answer (score 0):

In my oppinion you shoul make a css class like this

`.rotate {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}`

And use something like  `$(".arrowGreen").toggleClass("rotate");` on `onClick()` event

Comment: Exactly what I was writing. I think this is definitely the best way to do this, and the most maintainable and reusable.

Comment: This is a lot cleaner, thanks. This now allows the rotate to work in both directions, however the initial rotate still snaps back to it's default state for some reason.

What happens now:
Click accordion-btn element -> arrow span rotates 90 degrees -> once the rotation has completed, it snaps back to its original state (-90 degrees) -> click the element again and the arrow snaps back to the 90 degree angle and rotates back to normal from there.

:S

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your old one wasn't working is because your if statement for the transform was returning:

```
[Log] matrix(0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 1, -1, 0.00000000000000006123233995736766, 0, 0)  (08_10_14.html, line 34)
```

Which obviously doesn't match "rotate(90);"

You would of needed to do something as seen on: http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

I think @Cassian has the best answer for you though.